# Three.js print preview canvas not fully visible but screenshot it is

Tags: three.js, camera, scene

I have a three.js project running where i try to print the scene with the normal window.print() function.
It kind of worked but not as i expected.

This is my scene:
[image]

This is the screenshot with function (renderer.render) which works perfectly:
[image]

This is the print preview if i click "print" in the browser:
[image]

As you can see the print preview is not centered at all and also it is shifted a little bit to the left.
Can someone explain me either how i can shift the cameras view a little bit to the right so he takes the image centered from the view, or how i can transform the taken screenshot to the print preview because the screenshot taken with renderer.render(scene, camera) works very well?

This is the code:
`

```
function init() {
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                        antialias: true
                    }, { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.domElement.className = 'realCanvas';
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;

                pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
                pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

                controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
                controls.target.set(0, 50, 0);
                controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
                controls.minDistance = 350;
                controls.maxDistance = 2550;
                controls.minZoom = 350;
                controls.maxZoom = 2550;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 0.75;
                controls.panSpeed = 0.75;
                controls.rotateSpeed = 0.55;

                var minPan = new THREE.Vector3( - 1500,  - 1500,  - 1500);
                var maxPan = new THREE.Vector3(1500, 1500, 1500);
                var _v = new THREE.Vector3();

                controls.addEventListener("change", function () {
                    _v.copy(controls.target);
                    controls.target.clamp(minPan, maxPan);
                    _v.sub(controls.target);
                    camera.position.sub(_v);
                })

                controls.update();
                window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

                // stats
                stats = new Stats();
                stats.dom.classList.add("myStats");
                $('.myStats').css("display", "none");
                container.appendChild(stats.dom);
            }
```

`

This is the background init:
`

```
function initBackground() {
                container = document.createElement('div');
                container.classList.add("myCanvas");
                document.body.appendChild(container);
                container.style.cssText = 'position:fixed; top:0;';
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2.0, 100000);
                camera.position.set(-220, 100, -650); //(-220, 100, -650);

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcce0ff);
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xcce0ff, 5000, 10000);
                scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222, 0.75));

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.01);
                light.position.set(200, 450, 500);
                light.castShadow = true;
                scene.add(light);

                var gt = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("examples/textures/terrain/street4.jpg");
                var gg = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(32000, 32000);
                var gm = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                        color: 0xffffff,
                        map: gt
                    });

                ground = new THREE.Mesh(gg, gm);
                ground.rotation.x =  - Math.PI / 2;
                ground.material.map.repeat.set(640, 640);
                ground.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                ground.material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                ground.material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                // note that because the ground does not cast a shadow, .castShadow is left false
                ground.receiveShadow = false;
                ground.position.set(-20, -20, -20);
                scene.add(ground);
                $('div myCanvas').hide(); // before canvas but color picker colored square is also canvas
            }
```

`

This is the code for the taken screenshot which works good:
`

```
jQuery('#screenshot').click(function () {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                renderer.domElement.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Configurator");
                });
            });
```

`

This is the code i used for print preview, but it does not work as expected:
`

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('print');
            mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", () => {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                /*const c = document.getElementsByClassName("realCanvas");
                if(c.width === -1){
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    c.width=window.innerWidth;
                } else {
                    renderer.setSize(1050, 800);
                    //renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * 0.8, window.innerHeight * 0.8);
                    c.width=-1;
                }*/
                       
                        
            });
```

I tried to shift the cameras position but also the viewpoint but it does not work as expected.
I want to have the same view in the print preview as if i take a screenshot out of the scene.

Comment: Look at the top left corner of your screenshot, then look at the top left corner of your print preview. If you were to overlap them, you would see that the image is lining up as expected, it's just that it's not fitting to the page. You could attempt to either resize the renderer to fit the media type _before_ activating the print dialog, or you could try scaling/setting a maximum width for the image using the CSS `@media print` qualifier.

Comment: Yes you are right.. in the top left corner you can see this but i have also tried to set a new size as you can see at the end in my window.matchMedia('print') function. but i do not have a clue to properly scale the renderer... As a side node: in chrome the browser fits the screen also to the print preview in edge browser not.. what i can do is so manually set a scaling factor in edge browsers print settings but i need a more general solution.

Comment: Ok i solved it by adding width:1024px !important; and height:600px !important; to media query print. its not as beautiful as the screenshot but it is ok. Thanks anyway for helping.